# SQL Server query - select id count()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table . .

```
ID   item_ID   status    
----------------------------
1        1     'available'  
2        1     'available'  
3        1     'available'  
4        1     'reserved'   
5        2     'available'  
6        2     'available'  
7        3     'reserved'   
8        3     'reserved'   
9        3     'reserved'
```

I want my SQL query to return this result:

```
item_ID   quantity  
------------------
1            3      
2            2      
3            0
```

Please help with this. I'm not really good with T-SQL.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use aggregation, but first you need to filter only "available" products:

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) as quantity
FROM table
WHERE status = 'available'
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY item_id;
```

**EDIT:**

To get `0` you could use:

```
SELECT s.item_id, COUNT(t.item_ID) AS quantity
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT item_ID FROM table) s
LEFT JOIN table t
  ON s.item_ID = t.item_id
 AND t.status = 'available'
GROUP BY s.item_id
ORDER BY s.item_id;
```

Comment: @FrankieFernandez Sure, check upadated

Comment: Thanks sir it really helped me a lot and thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 2):

one more way is to use Sum with case

```
select item_id,
sum(Case when status='available' 
          then 1 else 0 end) as 'quantity
from
table
group by item_id
```